# Digit Factorial Sum?

Tags: project-euler

This question is founded in [Project Euler #34](https://projecteuler.net/problem=34). I originally solved the problem years ago but now I'm moving all the problems over to a new language. As I revisit this problem, I already know the answer but I don't know when to stop looking for the answer.

The task itself, minus lead up and notes, is

> Find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the
>   factorial of their digits.

The task of summing factorials is trivial. What isn't obvious to me is how do I know when I've found them all? I don't want to give away the answer to the question but here's what I know:

> I know that there are only 2 of these numbers: 145 as mentioned in the questions example and 40585.

When do I know to stop looking? How do I know that the biggest of these numbers is THE biggest and there won't be any more?

Comment: I don't know much about PE, but normally that would mean you have to *prove* the statement.

Comment: 9! = 362880. A number with n digits, all nines, will surpass 362880 * n when n is greater than 6.

Answer (score 3):

As Rubberchicken pointed out: the maximum value the sum of the factorials of an $n-$digit number is $9!(n)$ While the smallest value  a number of $n$ digits can have is $10^{n-1}$.

So you only have to check for numbers which satisfy $9!(n)>10^n\iff362880n>10^n\iff n<6.6$

So you only have to check up to $999999$